# Dynamic comparison of all columns for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, except

In SQL Server 2008R2:
What I am trying to do is take multiple rows from the same table and compare them to come up with the most complete row possible. I need the column lookup to be dynamic as the columns can change and access to the script that I am writing will not be easily alterable when live. The table has 277 columns (and counting), but let's try to simplify that for now:

```
REC  FIRST  LAST   MIDDLE    CITY     STATE    CTRY
1    John   Doe              Phoenix  UNK         
2    John   Doe    Quincy             AZ
3    J      Doe              Phoenix  AZ       USA
```

I would like to be able to select a "master" row, for this example let's assume REC 1, and where the value is NULL, select the value from the next row, and if that is null, the next row, etc. for all selected rows. **BONUS** if I can not only overwrite NULLS, but where value = 'UNK' that will be my next step. Ideally, a combined record for the above would appear as such:

```
REC  FIRST  LAST   MIDDLE    CITY     STATE    CTRY
1    John   Doe    Quincy    Phoenix  AZ       USA
```

I have toyed around with EXCEPT and various UNIONS, but haven't made it very far out of the gates as the dynamic aspect of this is stunting my progress.

If it is not possible to do this with multiple rows as requested above, I am happy with comparing 1 to 2, and then comparing 1 to 3.

**EDIT**
What I am trying to do is dynamically (and by dynamically, I mean to say that the columns and number of records may vary from occurrence to occurrence) create this:

```
create table #Something
(
    REC int
    , FIRSTName varchar(10)
    , LASTName varchar(10)
    , MIDDLE varchar(10)
    , CITY varchar(10)
    , STATE varchar(10)
    , CTRY varchar(10)
)

insert #Something
select 1, 'John', 'Doe', NULL, 'Phoenix', 'UNK', null union all
select 2, 'John', 'Doe', 'Quincy', NULL, 'AZ', null union all
select 3, 'J', 'Doe', NULL, 'Phoenix', 'AZ', 'USA'


select
          a.REC
         ,case
            when nullif(a.FIRSTName, 'UNK') is not null then a.FIRSTName
            when nullif(b.FIRSTName, 'UNK') is not null then b.FIRSTName
            when nullif(c.FIRSTName, 'UNK') is not null then c.FIRSTName
            else                                             a.FIRSTName
          end                       FirstName
         ,case
            when nullif(a.LASTName, 'UNK') is not null then a.LASTName
            when nullif(b.LASTName, 'UNK') is not null then b.LASTName
            when nullif(c.LASTName, 'UNK') is not null then c.LASTName
            else                                            a.LASTName
          end                       LastName
         ,case
            when nullif(a.MIDDLE, 'UNK') is not null then a.MIDDLE
            when nullif(b.MIDDLE, 'UNK') is not null then b.MIDDLE
            when nullif(c.MIDDLE, 'UNK') is not null then c.MIDDLE
            else                                          a.MIDDLE
          end                       MIDDLE
         ,case
            when nullif(a.CITY, 'UNK') is not null then a.CITY
            when nullif(b.CITY, 'UNK') is not null then b.CITY
            when nullif(c.CITY, 'UNK') is not null then c.CITY
            else                                        a.CITY
          end                       CITY
         ,case
            when nullif(a.STATE, 'UNK') is not null then a.STATE
            when nullif(b.STATE, 'UNK') is not null then b.STATE
            when nullif(c.STATE, 'UNK') is not null then c.STATE
            else                                         a.STATE
          end                       STATE
         ,case
            when nullif(a.CTRY, 'UNK') is not null then a.CTRY
            when nullif(b.CTRY, 'UNK') is not null then b.CTRY
            when nullif(c.CTRY, 'UNK') is not null then c.CTRY
            else                                        a.CTRY
          end                       CTRY
     from #Something    a
         ,#Something    b
         ,#Something    c
    where a.REC = 1
      and b.REC = 2
      and c.REC = 3
```

Comment: How do you know that this all the same person? I can see using MAX for most of this but you have nothing to indicate what makes up a group. What happens if you have Jane Doe? Why is she John and not Jane? Perhaps it is that your posted example is too simplified.

Comment: The user determines which records are to be used to combine. If the table has a Jane Doe, the user has not selected Jane. The user has selected records 1, 2, and 3 (conveniently). I do not need the logic, necessarily, for potential matches, but what to do after I have narrowed down my potential matches.

Comment: OK. So how do you know it should be John and not J?

Comment: The user, again, determines this. They select a master row - in the example that is row 1. Only if the value is NULL (or UNK) does the script need to consider looking in the subsequent rows.

Comment: Then you need to clarify a couple more things. What defines subsequent? The Rec column? And why does the middle name end up as "Quincy"? It is neither NULL or UNK on any row so shouldn't that one still be an empty string? Or do you want the max value for each column?

Comment: let's assume that I used the query "select * from table where REC IN (1, 2, 3) order by REC" to get the values in the initial table. Anything after 1, would be considered subsequent. Sorry, for readability, I replaced NULL as '' on the table - i figured it was easier to spot the NULL/empty values.
Sorry for the confusion, and thank you.

Comment: Doing this with cross join like you posted in your edit is going to be horrific from a performance perspective. I think you need better definition on the rules here before I am going to put any more effort into this.

Comment: Thanks to those that have helped ... I have come up with a solution that works - convoluted though it may be - which I will post once I have had a chance to clean it up a little bit. It's definitely not perfect, but it will get  the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something to get you started.

declare

@x varchar(2) = '1'
,@sql varchar(max)

while @x < (select max(REC) from #Something)

begin
set @sql = isnull(@sql,'')+  ' left join    #Something x' + @x + ' on a.REC = x' + @x+'.REC - ' + @x

set @x = @x +1
end

set  @sql =' select * from #Something  a    '+ @sql  + ' where a.REC = 1'

exec (@sql)

Comment: Alright, I have this added to the query, which is very cool to turn multiple rows into additional columns in one row. Are there limitations to the number of columns this will work with? I'm still not sure how I can implement an isnull per column comparing to the other columns of the same name now. I am trying out a few new things today as well, but I think this can come in handy, just not sure if it will work for my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have several missing business rules but here is an example that should at least point you in the right direction.

```
create table #Something
(
    REC int
    , FIRSTName varchar(10)
    , LASTName varchar(10)
    , MIDDLE varchar(10)
    , CITY varchar(10)
    , STATE varchar(10)
    , CTRY varchar(10)
)

insert #Something
select 1, 'John', 'Doe', NULL, 'Phoenix', 'UNK', null union all
select 2, 'John', 'Doe', 'Quincy', NULL, 'AZ', null union all
select 3, 'J', 'Doe', NULL, 'Phoenix', 'AZ', 'USA'

select 1
    , MAX(nullif(FIRSTName, 'UNK')) as FirstName
    , MAX(nullif(LASTName, 'UNK')) as LastName
    , MAX(nullif(MIDDLE, 'UNK')) as Middle
    , MAX(nullif(CITY, 'UNK')) as City
    , MAX(nullif(STATE, 'UNK')) as [State]
    , MAX(nullif(CTRY, 'UNK')) as Country
from #Something
```

Comment: hmmm ... it is not allowing me to add an edit to my original. The above doesn't really solve the dynamic portion of this problem. Using the populated table from your example, the query would need to be a dynamic version of ... 
select
    a.REC
   ,case
      when nullif(a.FIRSTName, 'UNK') is not null then a.FIRSTName
      when nullif(b.FIRSTName, 'UNK') is not null then b.FIRSTName
      when nullif(c.FIRSTName, 'UNK') is not null then c.FIRSTName
      else   a.FIRSTName
     end  FName
...
 from #Something    a, #Something    b, #Something    c
 where a.REC = 1 and b.REC = 2 and c.REC = 3

Comment: it needs to be dynamic in the columns and the number of tables though

Comment: Well the whole bit about unknown number of columns was missing in your question when I posted this.